Local/absolute maximum/minimum for functions whose graph is a straight line
My question: If the graph of a function is a straight line, how would you treat the local and absolute minimum/maximum?
Context: This idea came after trying to describe that an absolute minimum (or maximum) may not exist for some functions if its limit is $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. I would just assume it is all of it.
Example: $f(x) = 1$.

Do you mean what one defines as the min / max in that case?
Usually, one says that that doesn't exist.

Not sure to perfectly understand your question. In your example, for all $ x\in\mathbb R$, $x$ is a global maximum and a global minimum for $f$. If you take $f(x)=x$, $f$ has no local maximum and no local minimum on $\mathbb R$. Some functions whose graphs are not lines have no local extremum, for example $x\mapsto x^3$.

In the case that you mentioned, however, the min/max do exist, and are just the entire domain, since min / max are defined as a point that is $\geq$ or $\leq$ than all surrounding points

It is not clear what you are asking.

basically if you had a straight line like f(x) = 1, which derivative is 0, how would you describe the local min and max or abs min or max. The domain is not restricted here.

If it is a constant, then every point is a global $\max$ and a global $\min$.

Yeah that would make sense, also considering that extrema or local min or max is in repsect to the left and right hand of current domain, you could say that any current domain would be both a local and global max or min.
